# Hibernate mapping of lists

Tags: java, hibernate

I want to retrieve 3 columns from DB.More than 2 or 3 rows are retrieved while querying.This is the query `String query="select createdTime,receiptStatus,pointsEarned from Receipt where loyaltyId=:loyaltyId";
       List x= (List) entityManager.createQuery(query).setParameter("loyaltyId",loyaltyId).getResultList();`

I want to map the columns to a pojo class and pass the list(or use an object of that pojo).i created a pojo class like this

```html
public class TransactionHistoryEntity 
{
   private List<String> tranStatus;
   private List<String> tranDate;
   private List<String> pointsEarned;
 public List<String> getTranStatus() {
  return tranStatus;
 }
 public void setTranStatus(List<String> tranStatus) {
  this.tranStatus = tranStatus;
 }
 public List<String> getTranDate() {
  return tranDate;
 }
 public void setTranDate(List<String> tranDate) {
  this.tranDate = tranDate;
 }
 public List<String> getPointsEarned() {
  return pointsEarned;
 }
 public void setPointsEarned(List<String> pointsEarned) {
  this.pointsEarned = pointsEarned;
 }
}
```

created time should be mapped to tranDate,receiptstatus to tranStatus,pointsEarned to pointsEarned.

How can i achieve this ?? is my query correct ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Criteria cr= getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Receipt.class)
.add(Restrictions.eq("loyaltyId", loyaltyId))
.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
.add(Projections.property("createdTime"), "createdTime")
.add(Projections.property("receiptStatus"), "receiptStatus")
.add(Projections.property("pointsEarned "), "pointsEarned "))
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Receipt.class));
List<Receipt> receiptList = cr.list();
```

This Criteria act as `String query="select createdTime,receiptStatus,pointsEarned from Receipt where loyaltyId=:loyaltyId";` and map the return result to `List<Receipt>`

```
TransactionHistoryEntity trans = new TransactionHistoryEntity ();
List<String> tranStatus = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> tranDate = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> pointsEarned = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < receiptList.size() ; i++){
   tranDate.add(receiptList.get(i).getCreatedTime());
   tranStatus.add(receiptList.get(i).getReceiptStatus());
   pointsEarned.add(receiptList.get(i).getPointsEarned());
}
TransactionHistoryEntity.setTranStatus(tranStatus);
TransactionHistoryEntity.setTranDate(tranDate);
TransactionHistoryEntity.setPointsEarned(pointsEarned)
```

And this to map the return result to `TransactionHistoryEntity`

Comment: I am using JPA's entity manager for hibernate connection..like this..@PersistenceContext(unitName="aspu")
    private EntityManager entityManager;how can i use this ?Criteria cr = getCurrentSession().createCritiera(Receipt.class)..

Comment: It's throwing the compilation error..The method createCriteria(Class<Receipt>) is undefined for the type EntityManager

Comment: can i use this method ? ArrayList<TransactionHistoryEntity> x= (ArrayList<TransactionHistoryEntity>) entityManager.createQuery(query).setParameter("loyaltyId",loyaltyId).getResultList(); and do the relative changes in TransactionHistory ..so that mapping can be done ?

Comment: @Jill this answer if you are using hibernate not JPA

Comment: can you get the session ?

Comment: i am not allowed to use a sessionFactory method

Comment: `Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);` then use `session.createCriteria(Receipt.class)`

Comment: This is not working..getting a null pointer at Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException..